# Filter array subdocument based on document id and sub document key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am find subdocuments in a particular document by query

```
await Conversations.find(
{_id: room_id,"messages.sender": user_id}, function(err, success){
if(success){
  console.log("success",success)
  for (r of success){
    console.log(r);
  }
}
```

})

But the above query finds all the messages in that document. What is the best way to approach this problem instead of using aggregate? I have to write a modify query

My collection looks like:

```
{"data":{"_id":"5c2d4c2b116da2322616c387","messages":[{"msg_type":"text","time_created":"2019-01-03T00:03:25.055Z","_id":"5c2d514d70407c00102a67b2","sender":"0360a5ac-4b51-4c4d-b8b6-c6bad088135b","content":"Hi","seen":true},{"msg_type":"text","time_created":"2019-01-03T00:04:27.583Z","_id":"5c2d518b70407c00102a67b3","sender":"47a36731-f245-4c62-8a34-d7bc034634c9","content":"hi","seen":true},{"msg_type":"text","time_created":"2019-01-03T00:04:33.422Z","_id":"5c2d519170407c00102a67b4","sender":"0360a5ac-4b51-4c4d-b8b6-c6bad088135b","content":"Great","seen":true},{"msg_type":"text","time_created":"2019-01-03T00:04:39.487Z","_id":"5c2d519770407c00102a67b5","sender":"0360a5ac-4b51-4c4d-b8b6-c6bad088135b","content":"We have some conversations","seen":true}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to query an array of embedded documents.

```
let query = {
  _id: room_id,
  { messages: { $elemMatch: { sender: user_id } } }
}
await Conversations.find(query, function(err, success){
  if(success) {
   console.log("success",success)
    for (r of success) {
     console.log(r);
   }
 }
})
```

You can read about how to query an array of embedded documents [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch).

Comment: Didn't work, returned an empty array when I tried.
Previously I tried: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: I have updated the query in the answer and used the $elemMatch operator which matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your query. 
let query = {
   _id: room_id,
  messages: { $elemMatch: { sender: user_id } }

}
but it didn't work.

Comment: The syntax error maybe due to quotes around the property names.
let query = {
  "_id": room_id,
  { "messages": { $elemMatch: { "sender": user_id } } }
}
 If you can post the error, I can help you with that.

Comment: { "messages": { $elemMatch: { "sender": user_id } } }
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 

query should be an object